# Word Embedding for Convolution Neural Network

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, word2vec

I am trying to apply word2vec for convolution neural network. I am new with Tensorflow. Here is my code for pre-train layer.

```
W = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[vocabulary_size, embedding_size]),
                trainable=False, name="W")
embedding_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [vocabulary_size, embedding_size])
embedding_init = W.assign(embedding_placeholder)
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(embedding_init, feed_dict={embedding_placeholder: final_embeddings})
```

I think I should use `embedding_lookup` but not sure how to use it. I really appreace it someone could give some advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. As `embedding_lookup` works under the assumption that words are represented as integer ids you need to transform your inputs vectors to comply with that. Furthermore, you need to make sure that your transformed words are correctly indexed into the embedding matrix. What I did was I used the information about the index-to-word-mapping generated from the embedding model (I used gensim for training my embeddings) to create a word-to-index lookup table that I subsequently used to transform my input vectors.

Comment: Thanks Frobb, I am so happy to heard that. I tried to to use "embedding_lookup" , however I have a trouble passing argument. I have training data which are labelled, I used word2vec_basic.py to pre-train my data. I read on many website any some said that I have to map word vector to dictionary. Like this

`embedded_chars = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(W,dictionary)`


But it gave error, something with the dimension of Tensor, I tried to change variable 'dictionary' with 'data' or 'reverse_dictionary' but No help. Could you suggest me any advice. Thanks

Comment: The second argument of `embedding_lookup` is supposed to be the tensor that contains your input data. Take a look at the blog post that @Kashyap provided and you'll see that the second argument is the placeholder tensor for (batch) inputs. You just have to make sure that the words of your input data has been transformed to integers according to the word-to-index scheme that I mentioned earlier.

Comment: In the blog, writer said that "maps vocabulary word indices into low-dimensional vector representations". In the "word2vec_basic.py" the variable "data" store index of distionary. So I did like this:

`embedded_chars = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(W, data)`

I run it, and It did not give any errors. Do you thinks it is a correct ways ?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow. I haven't worked with this code before, but it appears the `data` variable of `word2vec_basic.py` (if you are referring to [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/word2vec/word2vec_basic.py) source code?) contains a word-to-index-transformed version of the unzipped original data that is contained in the `words` variable. Is this what you are trying to input to your CNN's embedding layer?

Comment: Yes, That is the code I used, I tried to match the index with the "Weight" I created. Here is the full code
`W = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[vocabulary_size, embedding_size]),
                trainable=False, name="W")`

`embedding_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [vocabulary_size, embedding_size])
embedding_init = W.assign(embedding_placeholder)`
`sess = tf.Session()`

`sess.run(embedding_init, feed_dict={embedding_placeholder: final_embeddings})`

`embedded_chars = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(W, data)`

`embedded_chars_expanded = tf.expand_dims(embedded_chars, -1)`

Comment: Well, if that is the data that you want to input to your CNN then everything is fine! You are looking up the embeddings of a bunch of text data that is integer-encoded in compliance with the indices of the embedding matrix. I just always assumed that you wanted to use the pre-trained embeddings in `W` for some other downstream task such as doing classification on some other dataset.

Comment: Yeah, that what is want to do.

Answer (score 2):

Tensorflow has an example using word2vec-cnn for text classification: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/skflow/text_classification_cnn.py

Comment: Thanks for your reply. their code is little difference. They use onehot vector to encode the word, not really word2vec
In this line: can I change it take my final_embedded ?


`byte_list = tf.reshape(learn.ops.one_hot_matrix(x, 256),
                         [-1, MAX_DOCUMENT_LENGTH, 256, 1])`

Answer (score 1):

I am doing something similar. I stumbled upon this blog that implements the paper "Convolutional neural networks for Sentence Classification". This blog is good. http://www.wildml.com/2015/12/implementing-a-cnn-for-text-classification-in-tensorflow/

Comment: Yeah I saw that, but they not use word-embedding.